# ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value not returning any value

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am creating a mvc web application to read user mails, send mail to a user and to receive the notifications using Microsoft Graph Api. My app is registered in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com. I'm able to get the return value for "ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value" after login and after subscription for notifications. But I'm not able to get the return value inside the Listen() function which is used to listen for the notifications. "Object reference not set to an instance of the object" is the error given.This is the Listen() function.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Listen()
    {
        // Validate the new subscription by sending the token back to Microsoft Graph.
        // This response is required for each subscription.
        if (Request.QueryString["validationToken"] != null)
        {               
            var token = Request.QueryString["validationToken"];
            return Content(token, "plain/text");
        }

        // Parse the received notifications.
        else
        {

            try
            {
                var notifications = new Dictionary<string, NotificationModel>();
                using (var inputStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
                {
                    JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(inputStream.ReadToEnd());
                    if (jsonObject != null)
                    {

                        // Notifications are sent in a 'value' array. The array might contain multiple notifications for events that are
                        // registered for the same notification endpoint, and that occur within a short timespan.
                        JArray value = JArray.Parse(jsonObject["value"].ToString());
                        foreach (var notification in value)
                        {
                            NotificationModel current = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NotificationModel>(notification.ToString());

                            // Check client state to verify the message is from Microsoft Graph. 
                            SubscriptionStore subscription = SubscriptionStore.GetSubscriptionInfo(current.SubscriptionId);

                            // This sample only works with subscriptions that are still cached.
                            if (subscription != null)
                            {
                                if (current.ClientState == subscription.ClientState)
                                {

                                    // Just keep the latest notification for each resource.
                                    // No point pulling data more than once.
                                    notifications[current.Resource] = current;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (notifications.Count > 0)
                        {

                            // Query for the changed messages. 
                         await GetChangedMessagesAsync(notifications.Values);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // TODO: Handle the exception.
                // Still return a 202 so the service doesn't resend the notification.
            }

            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(202);
        }
    }

    // Get information about the changed messages and send to the browser via SignalR.
    // A production application would typically queue a background job for reliability.
    public async Task GetChangedMessagesAsync(IEnumerable<NotificationModel> notifications)
    {
        List<MessageViewModel> messages = new List<MessageViewModel>();
        MessageModel message = new MessageModel();
        string serviceRootUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/";
        foreach (var notification in notifications)
        {
            SubscriptionStore subscription = SubscriptionStore.GetSubscriptionInfo(notification.SubscriptionId);
            string token;
            try
            {
                // Get the access token for the subscribed user.
                // accessToken = await GetAccessToken();
                HttpContextBase httpContext = HttpContext;
                token = await AuthHelper.GetAccessToken(httpContext);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, serviceRootUrl + notification.Resource);

            // Send the 'GET' request.
            GraphHttpClient graphHttpClient = new GraphHttpClient(token);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await graphHttpClient.SendAsync(request);

            // Get the messages from the JSON response.
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                string type = notification.ResourceData.ODataType;
                if (type == "#Microsoft.Graph.Message")
                {
                    message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageModel>(stringResult);
                    MessageViewModel messageViewModel = new MessageViewModel(message);
                    messages.Add(messageViewModel);                       
                }
            }
        }
        if (messages.Count > 0)
        {
            NotificationService notificationService = new NotificationService();
            notificationService.SendNotificationToClient(messages);  


        }



    }
```

This is the GetAccessToken() method where "ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value" is used.

```
public static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(HttpContextBase HttpContext)
    {
        string accessToken = string.Empty; ;
        // Load the app config from web.config
        string appId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppId"];
        string appPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppPassword"];
        string redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"];
        string[] scopes = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppScopes"]
            .Replace(' ', ',').Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        string userId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
            {
                // Get the user's token cache
                SessionTokenCache tokenCache = new SessionTokenCache(userId, HttpContext);

                ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
                    appId, redirectUri, new Microsoft.Identity.Client.ClientCredential(appPassword), tokenCache.GetMsalCacheInstance(), null);


                // Call AcquireTokenSilentAsync, which will return the cached
                // access token if it has not expired. If it has expired, it will
                // handle using the refresh token to get a new one.
                AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scopes, cca.Users.FirstOrDefault());

                accessToken = result.AccessToken;
            }

        // Get the current user's ID           

        return accessToken;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please add sample code showing what you've tried and where it's failing. At this time there much to work with here.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're saying is that you're not getting a user identity from the OWIN middleware on your notification endpoint. You shouldn't expect one! Your notification endpoint receives POSTS from the Office 365 service, which is not running as any particular user. It does include a bearer token in the `Authorization` header that you can use to validate it is truly from Microsoft, but that's it.

You should be mapping subscription IDs to user IDs on your side. That way when a notification comes in, you can correlate. You would also not want to be using a session-based token cache in that scenario. Instead you'd want to have something a bit more globally accessible to your app, like a database.